# How can I return a list from list of list Haskell

Tags: haskell

Basically, I have a function which checks every permutation of `[1..9]` by several conditions. Plus I have a function which checks if the sum of the list is equal to a number and a function which slice the list. The problem is that it returns an error `Couldn't match type 'Int' with 'Char'`. It points on the list which function has to return if all conditions are true.
Here is the code itself :

```
intSumList :: Int -> [Int] -> Bool
intSumList _ [] = True
intSumList x (y:ys)
                    | x == sum (y:ys) = True
                    | otherwise =  False
slice :: Int -> Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
slice from to s = take (to - from + 1)(drop from s)

find :: (Int,Int,Int,Int) -> [Int]
find (x,z,y,s) = checkPerm (x,z,y,s) l
                 where
                   l = L.permutations [1..9]
                   checkPerm (_,_,_,_ ) [] = ""
                   checkPerm (x,z,y,s) (p:pz)
                      | intSumList x (slice 1 5 p) && intSumList z (slice 2 6 p) && 
                        intSumList y (slice 4 8 p) && intSumList s (slice 5 9 p) = p
                      | otherwise = permutations (x,z,y,s) pz
```

Comment: `checkPerm` must have a return type of `[Int]`, so why are you saying `checkPerm _ () = ""` (type `[Char]`)?

Comment: Also, are you sure you want `intSumlist _ []` to be true? The sum of an empty list is generally considered 0, and you will never actually be calling `intSumList` on an empty list anyway; just use `intSumList x y = x == sum y`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your immediate problem is that `checkPerm` is returning an empty list of type `[Char]`, not `[Int]`, when it gets an empty list as its second argument.

However, `checkPerm` is basically reimplementing `Data.List.find`.

```
import qualified Data.List as DL
import Data.Maybe
import Control.Monad

find :: (Int,Int,Int,Int) -> [Int]
find (x,z,y,s) = fromMaybe [] (DL.find p l)
                 where makePred x lo hi p = intSumList x (slice lo hi p)
                       p1 = makePred x 1 5
                       p2 = makePred z 2 6
                       p3 = makePred y 4 8
                       p4 = makePred s 5 9
                       p = liftM4 (&&) p1 p2 p3 p4
                       l = DL.permutations [1..9]
```

`DL.find` returns `Nothing` if no match is found, or `Just l` for a a matching list `l`. `fromMaybe` converts this value to either an empty list or the found list. You might consider leaving the return value of `find` as `Maybe [Int]` instead, though.